# PowerShell - Send-MailMessage - Export mail to a file

Tags: email, powershell

I'm using the Send-MailMessgae Cmdlet to send an automated message with content each quarter.
The actual email works as expected etc however I want to save a copy of this email to a network share.

I've tried using Tee-Object to place it in a variable and then out-file to save it but this did not work.

I'm I'm thinking the only way i'm going to be able to do this is to just create a Here String with the details in it them output that.

Ideally I would like it to be in the .eml format as its a conformation that we are notifying users for the project the email is for.

I hope this makes sense.

Kind Regards,

Nigel Tatschner

Answer (score 0):

You could actually use Tee-Object to send the data straight to the file, instead of trying to use both Out-File and Tee-Object.

```
$logfile = 'C:\data\logfiles'

<data> | Tee-Object $logfile -Append
```

Comment: Thanks for the info, I think my issue is that Send-MailMessage dose not actually produce an output so when I Tee-Object it there is no object created and thus nothing in the .EML file.

Comment: Ahh, I see. What you want to do is Tee-Object or Out-File your output to a text document, and then use the -Attachments parameter to attach the file to your email. See this example: `Send-MailMessage -To jdoe@mydomain.com -From donotreply@mydomain.com -SmtpServer 10.0.0.1 -Port 25 -Subject 'Quarterly Email' -Body 'See attached log file' -Attachments $logfile`

Answer (score 0):

You can use System.Net.Mail.MailMessage

```
    # Based on MailMessageExt
# By Allan Eagle | 11 Jan 2009
# http://www.codeproject.com/KB/IP/smtpclientext.aspx

######################################
function createMailMessage([string]$from, [string]$to, [string]$subject) {
    [System.Net.Mail.MailMessage]$msg = New-Object -TypeName "System.Net.Mail.MailMessage" -ArgumentList $from, $to
    [System.Text.Encoding]$enc = [System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8
    $msg.SubjectEncoding = $enc
    $msg.Subject = $subject
    $msg.BodyEncoding = $enc
    return $msg
}
######################################
function mailAddAttachment([System.Net.Mail.MailMessage]$msg, [string]$filePath) {
    $fileExists = Test-Path -path $filePath -pathtype leaf
    if ($fileExists) {
        $fileName = Split-Path $filePath -Leaf
        [System.Net.Mail.Attachment]$att = New-Object -TypeName "System.Net.Mail.Attachment" -ArgumentList $filePath
        $att.ContentType.MediaType = [System.Net.Mime.MediaTypeNames+Application]::Octet
        $att.ContentType.Name = $fileName
        $att.ContentDisposition.FileName = $fileName 
        $att.ContentDisposition.DispositionType = [System.Net.Mime.DispositionTypeNames]::Attachment
        $att.ContentDisposition.Inline = $false
        $att.TransferEncoding = [System.Net.Mime.TransferEncoding]::Base64
        $msg.Attachments.Add($att)
        $att = $null
        return $true
    } else {
        $txt = "File ""$filePath"" not found"
        Write-Output $txt
        return $false
    }
}
######################################
function saveMailMessage([System.Net.Mail.MailMessage]$msg, [string]$filePath) {
    $binding = [System.Reflection.BindingFlags]::Instance -bor [System.Reflection.BindingFlags]::NonPublic
    $mailMessageType = $msg.GetType()
    $emlFilePath = $filePath
    [System.Type]$scType = [System.Type]::GetType("System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient")
    [System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient]$smtpClient = New-Object -TypeName "System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient"
    $scType = $smtpClient.GetType()
    [System.Type]$booleanType = [System.Type]::GetType("System.Boolean")
    [System.Reflection.Assembly]$assembly = $scType.Assembly
    [System.Type]$mailWriterType = $assembly.GetType("System.Net.Mail.MailWriter")
    [System.IO.FileStream]$fileStream = New-Object -TypeName "System.IO.FileStream" -ArgumentList ($emlFilePath,[System.IO.FileMode]::Create)

    [System.Array]$typeArray = ([System.Type]::GetType("System.IO.Stream"))
    [System.Reflection.ConstructorInfo]$mailWriterConstructor = $mailWriterType.GetConstructor($binding ,$null, $typeArray, $null)
    [System.Array]$paramArray = ($fileStream)
    $mailWriter = $mailWriterConstructor.Invoke($paramArray)
    #get MailMessage.Send(MailWriter,Boolean,Boolean)
    $doubleBool = $true
    [System.Array]$typeArray = ($mailWriter.GetType(),$booleanType,$booleanType)
    [System.Reflection.MethodInfo]$sendMethod = $mailMessageType.GetMethod("Send", $binding, $null, $typeArray, $null)
    if ($null -eq $sendMethod) {
        $doubleBool = $false
        [System.Array]$typeArray = ($mailWriter.GetType(),$booleanType)
        [System.Reflection.MethodInfo]$sendMethod = $mailMessageType.GetMethod("Send", $binding, $null, $typeArray, $null)
    }
    #get MailWriter.Close()
    [System.Array]$typeArray = @()
    [System.Reflection.MethodInfo]$closeMethod = $mailWriterType.GetMethod("Close", $binding, $null, $typeArray, $null)
    #execute MailMessage.Send(MailWriter,Boolean,Boolean)
    [System.Array]$sendParams = ($mailWriter,$true)
    if ($doubleBool) {
        [System.Array]$sendParams = ($mailWriter,$true,$true)
    }
    $sendMethod.Invoke($msg,$binding,$null,$sendParams,$null)
    #execute MailWriter.Close()
    [System.Array]$closeParams = @()
    $closeMethod.Invoke($mailWriter,$binding,$null,$closeParams,$null)
}
######################################
function Get-ScriptDirectory {
    Split-Path -Parent $PSCommandPath
}
######################################

$smtpServer = "smtp.here.com"
$smtpPort = 25

######################################

#$fileDir = Convert-Path "."
$fileDir = Get-ScriptDirectory
$fileDir

[System.Text.Encoding]$enc = [System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8

$dt = Get-Date
$dtStart = Get-Date $dt -Hour 0 -Minute 0 -Second 0
$baseName = $fileDir+"\report_"+$dtStart.toString("yyyy-MM-dd") 
$repName = $baseName+".csv"
$emlName = $baseName+".eml"

[System.Collections.ArrayList]$rep = @()
$rep.Add("This is a report")
$rep.Add("----------------")
for ($i=0; $i -lt 100; $i++) { 
    $index = $rep.Add("Line $i")
}
Set-Content $repName $rep

$from = "Sender <Me@here.com>"
$to = "Recipient <Them@there.com>"
$subject = "This is a report generated here on "+$dtStart.toString("yyyy-MM-dd")
$body = "$subject`n`n$repName"

[System.Net.Mail.MailMessage]$msg = createMailMessage $from $to $subject
$msg.IsBodyHtml = $false
$msg.Body = $body
mailAddAttachment $msg $repName
$emlName

[System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient]$smtp = New-Object -TypeName "System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient" -ArgumentList $smtpServer, $smtpPort
# $smtp.Send($msg)

saveMailMessage $msg $emlName
$msg.Dispose()

Remove-Item $repName

Pause
```